# LaTeX Labels: Any Constraints on Length

Tags: cross-referencing

Are there any limitations to how long the text in a `\label{text}` can be? I'm asking syntax-wise not aesthetic/practicality-wise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `\label` essentially defines a control sequence having a name built upon the label: for example, at the next run after having issued `\label{x}`, as part of the bookkeeping tasks done at `\begin{document}`, the macro `\r@x` will be defined.

Control sequence names can be, practically, arbitrarily long: the only limit is the “pool size”, because TeX has to remember the defined control sequence; on my system this is set to 6250000.

However, there is another constraint: TeX cannot read lines from a file if their length is above the value of `buf_size` (a variable set at run time, so it can in principle be changed). This variable, on my system, is set to 200000.

A method for defining control sequence names longer than `buf_size` can be conceived, but our problem are labels, which must be written to the `.aux` file: so a tad less than `buf_size`, because the annotation is

```
\newlabel{<label>}{{<number>}{<page>}}
```

and we need to have enough room for the other items besides `<label>`.

Comment: Can you recommend a good reference on such issues?

Comment: @YazanAhed There's something in TeX by Topic ([`texdoc texbytopic`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)) or the documentation of `kpathsea` ([`texdoc kpathsea`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/kpathsea/kpathsea.pdf))

Comment: How does `\label` prevent TeX from automatically inserting a line break every 80 characters? (I was expecting that to be a possible issue.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Seem to work with much more that 80 character without problems. Although the OP exclude the aesthetic/practical issues, the real problem is that such balels are not handy for human beings, and  in case of computer generated labels and references by some script, only 8 character are enough for 3025989069143040 labels (more or less) so ... why the hell one may want labels that do not fit on one line?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot The 80 character (actually 79) limit is about *printing text on the terminal*, which has nothing to do with the buffer size.

Comment: @Fran This was a conceptual rather than practical question. I'm currently working on handouts for students (~200 pages) in which I have many equations, and it's quite impossible to use meaningless labels efficiently (without keep going back and forth looking for the proper equation). [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org) has a nice autocomplete feature for labels that suggests possible references.

Comment: @egreg I thought the question was about *any* constraint on the length of a label rather than specifically relating to buffer size. The TeXbook says (p.228) regarding `\write` "Some implementations of TeX are unable to write long lines". I had thought the line limit applied to `\write` as well as `\message` but obviously I was wrong, so I realise that this isn't an issue with modern TeX distributions, but if you're using a distribution that can't write a long line, then this would be an issue for long labels and would therefore be considered a constraint on the length.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Doing `\write` is subject to `buf_size`; the 79 character limit is for *showing* on the screen. Knuth warned about possible limitation on `buf_size` due the the machine architecture: there used to be machines with fixed size records.